# Return key value pair if value exists in dictionary Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary and list:

```
dict_ = {'one':['a','b','c','d','e','f'],
'two':['g','h','l','m'],
'three':['x','y','z'],
'four':['xx','yy']}

ls = ['a','x','c','h','l']
```

I need to loop through the dict values and check if the items in ls exist in dict values, if so I would like to return a new dict with key/pair values, as follows:

```
new_dict = {'one':['a','c'],'two':['h','l'], 'three':['x']}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check overlaps with a set intersection -

```py
new_dict = {k: list(set(v) & set(ls)) for k, v in dct.items() if (set(v) & set(ls))}
```

**Output**

```
{'one': ['c', 'a'], 'two': ['l', 'h'], 'three': ['x']}
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I have other items in my dict whose values are not existent in ls. For ex; if I have key 'four':['xx','yy'], with this code, new_dict includes 'four':[] as an empty list. I will review the question example

Comment: What is your expected output in such cases?

Comment: As you can see 'four' contains none of the items from ls in the values, therefore I don't need it to be in new_dict

Comment: Perhaps I should just drop the items from the new_dict which has empty list as a value?

Comment: You can simply put that as a condition in the dictionary comprehension itself - see edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
_dict = {'one':['a','b','c','d','e','f'],
'two':['g','h','l','m'],
'three':['x','y','z']}

ls = ['a','x','c','h','l']

new_dict = {k:[v for v in l if v in ls] for k,l in _dict.items()}
print(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, a tip: you should never call variablke as "orange names" like int, float, dict, input, exc...

The solution:

```
dictt = {'one':['a','b','c','d','e','f'],
         'two':['g','h','l','m'],
         'three':['x','y','z']}

ls = ['a','x','c','h','l']

for k, v in dictt.items():
    dictt[k] = [el for el in v if el in ls]
```